# How to create Enum for hardcoded string in swift?

Tags: swift, enums

I have some hardcoded string, based on that i have created switch case. But instead of string in switch case i am trying to create Enum for same. but i am not sure how to do that. I dont want to use default case.

Do i need to access with raw value or any other better way to do ?

```
enum screens: String {
        case faq = "faq", contactus = "contactus", termncondi = "termncondi", dashoboard = "dashoboard"
    }

    func deepLink(text: String) -> String {
            switch text {
                case "faq":
                    return (FAQ.localized())
                case "contactus":
                    return (Contactus.localized())
                case "termncondi":
                    return (Term.localized())
                case "dashoboard":
                    return (Dashboard.localized())
                default:
                    return ""
            }
        }
```

Comment: It depends. What is the `text` parameter?

Comment: text will be the one which i am using in switch case, for ex. "faq", "contactus"...

Comment: because..i dont want to use default case..and want to maintain string only at one place..so that i can use same functionality at multiple places

Comment: Of course but where does the string come from? Is it an input of a text field or a value of a JSON API or what? If the string is arbitrary there is no benefit to use an enum.

Comment: its fixed set of strings from response

Comment: OK, then decode that set to an enum. That's what I meant with *it depends*.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define the enum and override the `rawValue` property like so:

```
enum Link {
    case faq
    case contact
    ...

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
            case .faq:
                return FAQ.localized()
            case .contact:
                return Contact.localized()
            default:
                return "Unknown case"
        }
    }
}
```

And get its `rawValue`.

```
let faqLink = Link.faq.rawValue
```

You can also perform a `switch` on an enum instance just like you do with a string.

Comment: Thanks for help..can you please suggest based on my updated question?  I am confused in how to perform enum in switch case

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do it that way, just use the regular enum with the rawValue, like shown in my answer.

Comment: I am new to it..can you help me in using it in switch case? i am passing string to function

Comment: That won't even compile, because enum raw values need to be hardcoded constants. You'd need to manually define the `rawValue` property of the `enum`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor You're right, my bad, I will edit the answer.

Comment: i am still not exactly got..that how can i use enum in switch ?

Comment: but here how it will know that faq has string "faq".. i am doing switch based on "faq" string

Answer (score 0):

In order to get hardcoded values do something like:

```
public extension String {
    static func getScreens(name: DeepLink) -> String {
        return name.rawValue
    }

  public enum DeepLink: String {
    case faq = "faq"
    case contactus = "contactus"
    
    // and so on
}
}
```

Comment: how to add this in switch case?